# Java3D: I can't see my triangle

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm very new to Java3D and try to show a triangle, but it does not show up, the frame is completely black.
If i add

```
bg.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
```

it shows a red square in the middle (so generally showing shapes should work, shouldn't it?)

I don't really know if the problem is with the construction of the triangle itself or with some other part of the View, e.g. the triangle is not in focus, too small, not lit, etc. Do polygons from TriangleArray have to be lit by a source, or do they appear as matt objects?

Here is the code:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfo;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.NormalGenerator;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Color4f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

public class Simulator extends Frame {

Point3f[] testTrianglePoints = {  
                                    new Point3f(0.0f ,0.0f, 1.0f),
                                    new Point3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.2f),
                                    new Point3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 1.2f)}; 

    Simulator() {
        System.out.println("Simulator window initiated");

    }

    public void run() {
        SimpleUniverse u = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();

        //bg.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));

        TriangleArray t_geo = new TriangleArray(9, TriangleArray.COORDINATES);
        t_geo.setCoordinates(0,testTrianglePoints);
        GeometryArray t_geoArray = (new GeometryInfo(t_geo)).getGeometryArray();
        Shape3D t_shape = new Shape3D(t_geoArray,new Appearance()); 
        bg.addChild(t_shape);

        u.addBranchGraph(bg);
        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

    }


}
`
```

Comment: Set a material into your appearance like in the example "PyramidExample": http://java3d.org/samples.html I assume that you use Java3D 1.6.0-Final.